# how to call the ref into mounted function

Tags: cordova, vue.js

```
<f7-input ref="input" placeholder="Enter a location" type="text"></f7-input>

mounted(){
  var n = this.$refs.input
}
```

it says:

Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of undefined"

is there a way to get the value of the input?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet!

Looks like the `mounted` event is too early to grab the `$refs`.  Move this code closer to where you actually need the value of the `input` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are actually using the component - did you add it into your `components` after the import?

Comment: what should i import sir?

Comment: f7-input - obviously your component is not using it

Comment: ahmm..sir i think framework7 is already imported at main.js or is there other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative way.
Make an event (like `this.$emit('loaded');`) in `mounted` method of your child componenent and use a function in your component to get `$ref`